# Converting an 8-digit integer into dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: php, date, date-conversion

So i have this function in my PHP script that is supposed to take the date as an 8-digit integer such as `01042012` and convert it to `01/04/2012` for displaying.

Currently i'm trying to use php's `date()` function as follows:

```
$int = 01042012;

$date = date("d/m/Y", $int);
```

Instead of `$date` having the value `01/04/2012` it shows as `13/01/1970`.

Is this because `date()` wants the date i pass to it to be in unix time? If so, would there perhaps be a more direct way to split the int after characters 2 and 4 and just insert the slashes, then recombine it? Like what `explode()` does, but i have no character to split with.

Comment: the easiest way is probably to cast your int into a string and use substr?

Comment: `01042012` is an octal number (equivalent to the decimal `279562`). You should look at the parameter descriptions for the [`date()` function](http://php.net/date); you cannot just throw anything into it and expect it to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An easy way to do it;

```
$int = 01042012;

$day = substr($int,0,2);
$month = substr($int,2,4);
$year = substr($int,4);

$date = $day.'/'.$month.'/'.$year;
```

Comment: Instead of 3x `substr()`, you can use `sscanf('01042012', '%02d%02d%04d', $day, $month, $year);`

Comment: Thanks, quick correction, month length in substr is 2 not 4   $month = substr($int,2, 2);

Answer (score 15):

Use [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) static method, who returns new `DateTime` object formatted according to the specified format:

```
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('dmY', '01042012');
echo $dt->format('d/m/Y');
```

Comment: I would use this, but my university has required that we use a version of MicroApache that uses PHP 5.2 Thank you though for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you are starting off with an int value and an int value of 01042012 will really be 1042012, as the leading zero has no meaning as an int.  If you started with "01042012" as a string, you would be much better starting position to accomplish you desired outcome.

Comment: Numbers that [start with `0` are octal](http://php.net/integer#language.types.integer.syntax), not integer.

Comment: Ahh, very good!  Thanks for the correction.  Still makes much more sense to use a string in this situation, but thanks for correcting/teaching me :-)

Comment: Yes, a string makes more sense. Using a better format, such as a UNIX timestamp or a date/time parsable by `strtotime()`, would make *even more* sense.